# Can't use method from a controller class

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, model-view-controller

I'm trying to structure my Express.js code however I'm running into a problem trying to use my class method from the controller.

Heres what it looks like:

product.service.ts

```
export class ProductService {
  constructor(private readonly model: Model<ProductType>) {}

  public getAllProducts = () => {
    return this.model.find({});
  };
}
```

product.controller.ts

```
export class ProductController {
  constructor(private readonly service: ProductService) {}

  public getProducts = async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    const response: ProductType[] = await this.service.getAllProducts();
    res.send(response);
  };
}
```

products.router.ts

```
import express, { Router } from 'express';
import { ProductController } from '../controllers/product.controller';

const router: Router = express.Router();

router.get('/', ProductController.getProducts);
```

The problem is in my products.router.ts, it keeps saying

> Property 'getProducts' does not exist on type 'typeof ProductController'.ts(2339)

Could anyone advise me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're never instantiating your controller, never passing it a service. `getProducts` is not a static method. If you want to use it like that, use a singleton object literal instead of a `class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility:

```
import express, { Router } from 'express';
import { ProductController } from '../controllers/product.controller';

const router: Router = express.Router();

const productModel = /* however you create Model<ProductType> */;
const productService = new ProductService(productModel);
const productController = new ProductController(productService);

router.get('/', productController.getProducts);
```

Comment: In order to have `this` pointing at the ProductController object in your `getProducts` function, you may actually want:

`router.get('/', productController.getProducts.bind(productController));`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should create an instance of this class to be able to access it